# Conditional generic type

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I wrote the same code twice with a different typing but they are identical.

The first compiled:

```js
type X<B extends boolean> = { b1: B } & (B extends true ? { a1: 1 } : { a2: 2 })

function f<B extends boolean>(x: X<B>) {
  console.log(x)
}

function f2(b: boolean) {
  f(b ? { b1: true, a1: 1 } : { b1: false, a2: 2 })
}

f2(true)
```

The following has an error:

```js
type X<B extends { b1: boolean }> = { b1: B['b1'] } & (B['b1'] extends true ? { a1: 1 } : { a2: 2 })

function f<B1 extends boolean>(x: X<{ b1: B1 }>) {
  console.log(x)
}

function f2(b: { b1: boolean }) {
  f(b.b1 ? { b1: true, a1: 1 } : { b1: false, a2: 2 })
                                 ^^^^^
                                 ERROR ts(2345)
}

f2({ b1: true })
```

error:

```
Argument of type '{ b1: true; a1: number; } | { b1: false; a2: 2; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'X<{ b1: boolean; }>'.
  Type '{ b1: true; a1: number; }' is not assignable to type 'X<{ b1: boolean; }>'.
    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'a1' does not exist in type 'X<{ b1: boolean; }>'.ts(2345)
```

## Question

Why the second code has an error? How can I fix the typings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, B extends boolean. This allows Typescript to infer the type more strictly, and allows B to be reduced to either `true` or `false` as needed. Consider:

```
const test: X<boolean> = {b1: true, a2: 2}; // Compiles. Likely not what you want
const test2: X<true> = {b1: true, a2: 2}; // Does not compile, as expected
```

That means that when you call f2,  the type of `{ b1: true, a1: 1 }` is actually `X<true>`, and `{ b1: false, a2: 2}` is `X<false>`.

In that example, if you assign the result to a variable, it won't compile, as you won't be able to strictly define the type.

```
function f2(b: boolean) {
  const argument = b ? { b1: true, a1: 1 } : { b1: false, a2: 2 };
  // type is { b1: boolean; a1: number; a2?: undefined } | { b1: boolean; a2: number; a1?: undefined; }
  f(argument); // compile error
}
```

In your second example, Typescript just does not have enough information to assess the type at compile type.

This modification on your second function allows it to compile

```
function f2(b: { b1: boolean }) {
  if (b.b1) {
    f({ b1: true, a1: 1 })
  } else {
    f({ b1: false, a2: 2 })
  }
}
```

For more information about conditional types, check https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types

Comment: What can we modify in the second code so Typescript will have what it needs to infer the types correctly?

Comment: @StavAlfi Updated the answer

Comment: this is not want I was looking for but i guess it's just not possible (yet?). so I guess that it's good enough. thanks!